# Codeigniter: View foreach call Controller

Tags: codeigniter, controller, view

> Error:
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> - Message: Undefined variable: calificacione
> - Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

---

- what is wrong?
- In `Controller` the variable is created:  `$data['calificacione']`
- And in the view is called on `foreach`

My View:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Calificacione</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php 
                    foreach ($calificacione as $key => $value) {
                      echo "<pre>";print_r($value);echo "</pre>";
                    }
                  ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php  ?></td>                        
                    </tr>
                  <?php } ?>     
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

My Controller

```
class Provedore extends CI_Controller{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model(['Provedore_model','Provedor_calificacione_model','Provedor_calificacione_model','Personas_contato_model','Direcione_model']);
} 

/*
 * Listing of all provedores
 */
function index()
{
    $data['provedores'] = $this->Provedore_model->get_all_provedores();
    $data['calificacione'] = $this->Provedor_calificacione_model->get_all_provedor_calificaciones();

    $data['_view'] = 'provedore/index';
    $this->load->fullView('layouts/main',$data);
}
```

Comment: Instead of passing data as second argument, load variables before loading view: `$this->load->vars($data); $this->load->fullView('layouts/main');`. Try that way. (Check [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars) also.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below mentioned possibilities.

Are you getting data from model or any error.

```
var_dump($data['calificacione']);
die;
$data['_view'] = 'provedore/index';
$this->load->fullView('layouts/main',$data);
```

Please share your output so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

in your model `Provedore_model` `get_all_provedores` may has some arguments like

```
function get_all_provedores ($argument)
{
// your database query
}
```

and you did'nt fulfilling that argument

Answer (score -1):

```
//try this

 function index()
{ 
$provedores = $this->Provedore_model->get_all_provedores();
 $data['provedores'] = $provedores;
 $calificacione = $this->Provedor_calificacione_model->get_all_provedor_calificaciones();
  $data['calificacione'] = $calificacione;
 $this->load->view('layouts/main',$data)
 $this->load->view('provedore/index',$data)
}
```

Comment: The same mistake continues

Comment: Same error message displaying that you were getting before.@cristian marques.